# Decoding Base64 string doesn't translate special chars

Tags: c#, utf-8, decode

I have an XML file encoded as Base64, this file has embeded images in it.

My problem is when i try to decode it:

[String sample is here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=97F4B143ABA595E3!237856&authkey=!AKdVGQCYsU87Zfg&ithint=folder%2Ctxt)

Here is my code:

**UTF8 Version:** This one can be decoded and loaded into XML but special chars doesn't decode properly (á,é,í,ó,ú,ñ,Ñ) all are decoded as **? symbol**.

```
    public XmlDocument GetXmlDocument(string Base64Text)
    {
        string DeCoded = string.Empty;
        XmlDocument Datos = new XmlDocument();
        byte[] Base64 = Convert.FromBase64String(Base64Text);
        DeCoded = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Base64);
        Datos.LoadXml(DeCoded); 
        return Datos;
    }
```

**UTF7 Version:** This one can be decoded and special chars are all decoded properly. If Has images can't be loaded to XML Document due embeded images doesn't decode properly.

```
    public XmlDocument GetXmlDocument(string Base64Text)
    {
        string DeCoded = string.Empty;
        XmlDocument Datos = new XmlDocument();
        byte[] Base64 = Convert.FromBase64String(Base64Text);
        DeCoded = Encoding.UTF7.GetString(Base64);
        Datos.LoadXml(DeCoded); 
        return Datos;
    }
```

**EDIT 1:** My encoded Base64 string came from VFP app it was encoded using 
    **VFP Sintax** 
    STRCONV(lcImage, 6)

```
In VFP help it says: 

Converts character expressions between single-byte, double-byte, UNICODE, and locale-specific representations.
```

And **6** means:

```
6   Converts UNICODE (wide characters) to double-byte characters.
```

I'm trying with UTF7 and UTF8, just testing wich one could translate my string.

I just need my original XML with it's embeded images in .NET,  If this is imposible with standard functions, How can I catch and translate **? symbol** s to readable chars?

Comment: Decoding must be exact reverse of encoding. Not really clear why you are guessing between Utf8 and Utf7.... Side note: You may consider improving your question by actually providing [MCVE] and instead of some strange XML manipulation.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yes my mistake trying to put two versions of my function in the same code. Please see my Edits.

Comment: Still, if the XML file was UTF-8 + base64 then you need to use UTF-8 to decode, if it was UTF-7 + base64 encoded, then you need to use UTF-7 to decode, etc. The important thing is that you need to decode it the way you encoded it, like Alexei said.

Comment: It seems that you might also be mixing Windows-1252 encoding (from the answer by Anton) with UTF-16 (?) encoding from the `STRCONV` -- this would be bad. You should use the same locale for encoding the image as the file you'll be embedding it in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your XML document:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding="Windows-1252" standalone="yes"?>
```

So, this works:

```
DeCoded = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(Base64);
```

Comment: Ah, good catch on the `encoding="Windows-1252"` in the OneDrive file. There might be some issues with the embedded image using a different encoding, though, if I read the `STRCONV(lcImage, 6)` from the edit correctly.

Comment: @Anton-Gogolev, Tks... That's what I love StackOverflow, because of people like you, no matter if question is obvious for some one (who down vote this question). People like me comes to stackoverflow for HELP. And There is always someone willing to help.